# How to get digest-authentication working on Team Foundation (2008) Project Portal sites

Tags: windows, authentication, sharepoint, tfs

I am just starting out with Team Foundation Server 2008, and one of the hangups I've experienced is the following:

I create a new Team Project, as well as a Project Portal (which I believe is just a Sharepoint site).  When I go to view the project portal in the browser, it prompts me for a username and password.  I want it to use digest authentication (meaning it just uses my current domain credentials).  I have this working on the Team Foundation site itself, but I cannot seem to get it working at all on the Project Portal sites that TFS creates for me.

Any thoughts?  I've already attempted to set digest authentication on the Default Website as well as the Sharepoint Central Administration (v3) site, both of which did not fix my problem.

EDIT: I am running this on Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the pool account running the TFS sites is in your domain.
Your host may also not be in the 'Safe sites' / 'Intranet Zone' config in Internet Explorer, you can make it a trusted site and mark in the advanced options to send username and password.